# Why the following setup does not violate Earnshaw's Theorem?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

[image][image: 1]I am afraid I am missing something about Earnshaw's theorem, how does this not violate it?

Comment: Note that the given position isn't a stable equilibrium for a negative charge;  there's an implicit assumption that the test charge is positive.  (This isn't relevant to Earnshaw's theorem, though, just a comment about whether the question is well-posed.)

Comment: Earnshaw's theorem requires 3 dimensions, while the example has only 2.

Comment: @A.P. That is no question here you can replace the 3 charges at the corner by spherical charges(maybebe electrons) and study the configuration at large distance, the number of dimension has got nothing to do with answer whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equilibrium in this problem is stable only because of the constraint on the motion of the test charge to be along $PQ$. In some other direction the equilibrium is unstable, but the particle is not free to move in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Earnshaw's theorem says that you can't use static electric fields to create an equilibrium point that is stable in *all* directions. You have found one direction where the equilibrium point is stable. But there must be another direction in which it is unstable.

In this case specifically the unstable direction is the z direction.